# Using vertex attributes for GLSL with LibiGL

Tags: c++, glsl

I am doing some computationally heavy stuff on meshes with libiGL(c++) and am trying to move these computations over to the GPU. To start off, I am trying to get a basic piece of code running but the attribute values do not seem to get passed on to the shaders.

```
int m = V.rows();//vertices
P.resize(m);
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    P(i) = i / m;
}

std::map<std::string, GLuint> attrib;

attrib.insert({ "concentration", 0 });
igl::opengl::create_shader_program(
    mesh_vertex_shader_string,
    mesh_fragment_shader_string,
    attrib,
    v.data().meshgl.shader_mesh);
GLuint prog_id = v.data().meshgl.shader_mesh;
const int num_vert = m;
GLuint vao[37 * 37];//37*37 vertices
glGenVertexArrays(m, vao);
GLuint buffer;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindVertexArray(vao[i]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float), P.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)(i*sizeof(float)));
}
```

The red color of each vertex should be dependant on its ordering (from 0 red to 1 red) but instead the mesh is colored with no red at all.
I am basing myself off of this code :https://github.com/libigl/libigl/issues/657 and http://www.lighthouse3d.com/cg-topics/code-samples/opengl-3-3-glsl-1-5-sample/.

I modified the shader strings accordingly by adding the following lines:

**Vertex Shader**

```
in float concentration;
out float c;
c = concentration;
```

where the last line is in main();

**Fragment Shader**

```
in float c;
outColor.x = c;
```

where the last line is in main().

What am I doing wrong?
Edit: OpenGL version used is actually 3.2

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm new to this so I might be wrong, but I can't use uniform since I plan to have the value(s) be modified during the shader stage. The mesh is drawn exactly as in the github link, using the Viewer object. The other vertex attributes are also the same as in the github link, but I'm not sure how they are passed... I'll see if I can make an example, although LibiGL does require a bit of setting up.

Comment: The uniforms, attributes, and textures are passed properly. The Viewer function calls do it, I just haven't looked much into it.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Looked a bit more into it, there's a meshgl class that is used that has various vbo and vao fields. I'm starting to think I need to use one of these vaos to pass my attribute. looking at the links you previously posted, I'd say I need to use the vao_mesh field which is used to store the vbos for the vertices, normals, textures, etc. Seem correct?